# How to only output a column that has constant neighbors?

Tags: awk

INPUT

```
AA XXX Y1Y ZZZ GG dhz
rr (AAAa) XXX Y2Y ZZZ TT GGGG UU
```

OUTPUT

```
Y1Y
Y2Y
```

The input lines could vary.. only the XXX before the Y1Y and the ZZZ after Y1Y is constant (they are the neighbors of XXX and ZZZ like this). Y1Y could be anything, ex.: Y1Y, Y2Y, Y1T, etc.

**Q:** how can I get the OUTPUT with awk or sed or grep? (or are there any better tool for this?)

**UPDATE** (problem): why doesn't it works when having "." in the Y1Y?

```
[user@notebook ~] echo 'XXX Y1Y ZZZ' | grep -Po "(?<=XXX )(\w+)(?= ZZZ)"
Y1Y
[user@notebook ~] echo 'XXX Y1.Y ZZZ' | grep -Po "(?<=XXX )(\w+)(?= ZZZ)"
[user@notebook ~]
```

Comment: no, and I updated the "INPUT"

Comment: Are the neighbors always XXX and ZZZ?

Comment: yes, as I wrote!

Comment: Yes but it isn't clear whether XXX and ZZZ are stand ins for something else are literally XXX and ZZZ. Just my $0.02.

Comment: XXX and ZZZ are constant strings, just censored..

Comment: OK, see my answer, that should be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` and the PCRE facility it provides to do this:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=XXX )\S+(?= ZZZ)" data.txt 
Y1Y
Y2Y
```

#### Details

This solution makes use of the lookbehind and lookahead feature of PCRE, which can match fixed length strings.

The above looks behind every `\w+` to see if it's `XXX` and head of every `\w+` seeing if it's `ZZZ`. If it is then it's a match. The `-o` switch to `grep` tells it to only print the matches, i.e. `\w+`.

#### Followup, can you do it with sed?

I don't think that this problem can be solved using `sed`. There are 2 approaches as I see it.

1. save potential matches in a side variable, if you encounter ZZZ, then print them
2. s/XXX ..our string.. ZZZ/ ..our string../

No. 1 seems like a fair amount of work so I'm not going to even attempt it. Here's what happens with approach No. 2.

```
$ sed 's/.*XXX \(.*\) ZZZ.*/\1/' data.txt 
Y1Y
Y2Y
AAAa YXX Y2Y ZZZ TT GGGG UU
```

So it can find the matches just fine, but it doesn't do anything for lines that don't match. There might be a way to instruct `sed` to delete these lines, in which case this would be an alternate solution.

Comment: is it impossible to do this in sed? :D

Comment: @gaskopeter - I think it would be trickier b/c sed is a line editor, so you'd have to save the potential matches in a temp. variable until you can confirm that the sub strings after the match are ZZZ.

Comment: @gaskopeter - your welcome, and thank your for the Q.

Comment: I tested it and got 1 problem, sorry:D

Comment: @gaskopeter - yes the problem's with the \w+. That matches only word characters (A-Z0-9). Period isn't one of them. What characters are allowed for the matched substring?

Comment: @gaskopeter - see update, it now matches everything except a space.

Comment: I need some time to test it, will be back